# Bluetoothctl scan response in cluster setup

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, cluster

I have a raspberry Pi cluster with 4 nodes. I wanted to run bluetoothctl in the master node and receive just the scan response in other three nodes in the cluster. Please help me how to do this.

Thanks
Ram